# Error install nodejs...SSL_COMP_get_compression_methods

Tags: macos, node.js

installing node-v0.4.8 on mac os x leopard, I get the following error:

```
../src/node_crypto.cc:2917: error: ‘SSL_COMP_get_compression_methods’ was not declared in this scope
Waf: Leaving directory `/usr/local/node-v0.4.8/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): 
    {task: cxx node_crypto.cc -> node_crypto_4.o}


make: *** [program] Error 1
```

Anyone experienced this error installing the latest nodejs?  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: are you compiling with superuser privs in that /usr/local ?

Comment: idk, guessing blind since I don't do OSX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of openssl included with MacOSX is not the latest. I would recommend grabbing the latest version here:

http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.0d.tar.gz

Extracting it to your directory of choice, cd to that directory:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

The last `sudo` command will require you enter your admin password. Then go to the node.js source directory and:

```
$ ./configure --openssl-includes=/usr/local --openssl-libpath=/usr/local
```

This will tell node to use the custom built openssl we just compiled and installed. Then finally:

```
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't know how to comment instead of post an answer. But this didn't work for me. Same SSL error. This however worked:

http://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2011/04/10/node-without-ssl/

This is fine for now since I'm just prototyping, but obviously lack of SSL sucks.